# Starting MariaDB in DockerToolBox under Kitematic

Tags: mariadb, docker-machine, kitematic

Although I found this reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/, it's for MySQL, not MariaDB, and I don't see how it connects to Kitematic. I'm running on Win 10 home, so Docker Toolbox is running a Linux VM using Oracles' Virtual Box.

Text of error is: 
mysql database uninitialized and password option not specified.

I was just trying to learn the concepts of Docker, and picked MariaDB from a menu of preconfigured machines; it downloaded then gives the above error when it starts.

[image]

Do I configure this inside the Kitematic tool? Or do I have to edit some file on disk? Or other?

Answer (score 1):

in kitematic add Environment Variables 
key MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
Value PASSWORD
and click in start